# How to append text to file using batch-script cross-platform

Tags: linux, windows, macos, shell, file

How can we append `"some text"` to `file.txt` without the quotes, from a batch file? Text files and only using what is "standard" on windows, linux and mac.

I did try:

```
echo "some text" >> file.txt
```

it works for linux but on windows it does output the quotes to the file too;

but like mentioned we do need a cross-platform command (i.e. since we will use it in MakeFile of cross-platform project but that is another subject)

Comment: Cross platform is not exactly cross platform... As you have discovered, `echo` in windows `cmd.exe` does not handle quotes specially. From a `Makefile` standpoint this is an issue. (not to mention the difference between `xcopy/cp`, `del/rm`, etc...) What I have found works well is a `Msys` install on windows to provide a minimum Linux system you can access simply by including the `Msys/1.0/bin` directory in your windows PATH. Not a true cross-platform solution, but a convenient workaround.

Comment: Are you okay with using Python because that way, you can make it cross-platform?

Comment: @Samarth using any tool that is installed by default on platforms and is in `path` would be perfect, but still what is the `Python` command, and does `Python`'s installer put it into `path` env-var or not?

Comment: Python doesn't come installed in Windows, so that won't serve your purpose then.

Comment: Why does it have to be a single file that magically runs on all platforms? Why not have separate scripts for e.g. /bin/sh and cmd.exe?

Comment: @melpomene: at last after searching and asking, we ended up with generating the `MakeFile` based on the underlying platform using an external tool (that seemed to be our only option)

Answer (score 1):

You said `echo "some text" >> file.txt` worked but you also got the quotes. It was right you just have to remove the quotes then it will work **;**).

Comment: +1 for being right, but another difference is that: Windows will append a line-fade to the end of the file (and that each time we run the `echo some text >> file.txt` command), which is anything else than cross-platform (o_O)